# Why I am not receiving a hexadecimal number as output when I print a pointer address with %p?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, memory-management

I have written a program while learning pointers in c and facing a problem. My code was to print the address of the variable which should be a hexadecimal number. But why I am receiving an integer number instead of a hexadecimal number. Please help me out to print the hexadecimal number starting with "0x" . Thank you.

Note that my IDE was Visual Studio Code and the compiler I am using is GCC.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *a = "abcd";
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("%p\n",&a[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Output :

```
00405064
00405065
00405066
00405067
```

I was expecting a number starting with "0x"

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions.

Comment: Those are hexadecimal numbers. So they do not start with `0x`, so what? That is just a marker for using hexadecimal in source code. Numbers can be written in hexadecimal, decimal, octal, binary or other bases even if they are not explicitly marked. They should be explicitly marked for clarity of communication, but it is no absolutely required. The C standard does not say exactly what format an implementation has to use for the `p` conversion, and your C implementation is using hexadecimal but not marking it with `0x`. That looks like a Microsoft choice.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand this. This is actually a hexadecimal number. I have tried to concatinate the hexadecimal number with decimal number and got some alphabaic number which also helped me to understand the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's not defined what `%p` uses as a format to print the address.

However, it's common for it to be displayed in hexadecimal.

So, if you want to print the hexadecimal number of a pointer *the most portable way I know of* (C99 & above) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h> // PRIxPTR

int main(void) {
    const char *a = "abcd"; // 'const' because a is not modifiable

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        uintptr_t tmp = (uintptr_t)&a[i];

        printf("0x%" PRIxPTR "\n", tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: The source you cite says it is a Linux page, but it is not clear what implementation of the C standard library OP is using. The C standard does not require hexadecimal for a `p` conversion. C 2018 7.21.6.1 8 says, for `p`, “The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Although that is a good point, tell me an implementation that doesn't use hexadecimal notation for `%p`.

Comment: OP’s implementation is printing in hexadecimal but not “as if by %#x or %#lx”. The `#` modifier with `x` or `lx` causes `0x` to be printed. The documentation you cite is wrong for the example in the question.

Comment: @marco-a Microsoft's C runtime libraries print `%p` **without** prepending `0x`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil While I like to be pedantic myself, I think this is pretty much an insignificant detail. I can see that the premise of the question is wrong to begin with (if `%p` is not guaranteed to have _any_ format whatsoever). However, my response isn't authoritative to begin with and shouldn't be taken as such. My response is based on experience with C, and I'm still waiting for you to point out an implementation that doesn't use hexadecimal notation for `%p`. Still, I appreciate your feedback and I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have updated my answer once more to incorporate the undefinedness of the format of `%p` with an (hopefully valid) example how to print the address of a pointer in a hexadecimal format regardless of the implementation used.

Comment: (Not really an answer to your question, but) *if* `%p` had existed back in [V7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix)/[PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11) days, I have always imagined that it would have printed in octal, because for whatever reason octal was the popular notation for addresses on that platform / in those days.

Comment: It's really sad that the C "Standard" (in quotes because it seems like it's not really a complete standard in my opinion) does allow for such shenanigans in modern days. I wouldn't call it a "standard" because I've read the "is implementation defined" too many times in regards to the C language ; it's ridiculous. I don't know if C11 (and above) do make any effort in ditching completely ambiguous "features" that exist solely for extremely obscure use cases and/or platforms.

Comment: @marco-a What practical problem is caused by the looseness of the definition of `%p`?

Comment: @SteveSummit It's not `%p` _specifically_ but more like the "attitude" of deferring **key** details to an implementation, rather than defining them in the standard. `NULL` (the void pointer) is such an example: it's not guaranteed by the standard to be equivalent to `0` (all bits to zero, that is). Another example is the ambiguity of strings (`char *`) they're neither `signed` nor `unsigned`, you can switch the behaviour with a flag in gcc AFAIK, but it's another inconsistency. Or how about that `char` can _actually_ be 16bit?

Comment: Another example that comes to mind is the `bool` data type, that wasn't even in the original C standard. It was later added with the ridiculous requirement to be able to **at least** hold `0` and `1`. I'm sorry, there's just no way a real computer system is going to be implementing booleans on a bit by bit level - it's just not how it works. Real computers use byte-addressable memory, so that's the lowest a real computer can meaningfully distinct memory.

Comment: I'd like to elaborate more, but comments are limited to 600 characters, so I'm not going to do that.

Comment: @marco-a "print the hexadecimal number of a pointer in a portable way (C99 & above) you should use:" and `uintptr_t tmp = (uintptr_t)&a[i];` is interesting, yet does have the caveat the `(u)intptr_t` are _optional_ types, even if very commonly available.  IAC, conversion to `uintptr_t` does not certainly have the same bit pattern as the pointer.  I suppose its is a trade-off between getting always hex output vs. always seeing the true pointer.

Comment: @marco-a If you want a language that defines everything, that leaves little or nothing up to the implementation, please, use Java.  That's one of Java's goals.  But it simply isn't one of C's goals, so if that's what you want, C is always going to disappoint you.

Comment: @SteveSummit You're misinterpreting my argument. I know most of C quirks are of historic nature, but I think it's time for C to leave that behind and create a new, modern standard, presumably under a different name. You can't run Java on embedded systems with limited resources, so you don't really have a choice but to use C. Also you can't beat C in performance, **but** that isn't because of things like "let's let the implementation decide [the behaviour]" it's just that C is really low level, which is good. Some things (as mentioned) are just ridiculous though.

Answer (score -2):

Everything seems just fine in your code sample. I tested it on three different online compilers and produced expected output:

Output on compiler 1:

```
0x55cf7d06c004
0x55cf7d06c005
0x55cf7d06c006
0x55cf7d06c007
```

Output on compiler 2:

```
0x55dfc15c0004
0x55dfc15c0005
0x55dfc15c0006
0x55dfc15c0007
```

Output on compiler 3:

```
0x4005c0
0x4005c1
0x4005c2
0x4005c3
```

So, I guess is something in your IDE/compiler.

Comment: ```00405064
00405065
00405066
00405067``` are hexadecimal numbers. They're just not prefixed with ```0x```. It's not required that they be prefixed with ```0x```. There's nothing wrong with his compiler.

Comment: I thought format specifier "%p" produces hexadecimal result, always beginning with "0x" prefix.

Comment: An implementation may choose to do so, but the C standard doesn't mandate it.

Comment: Specifically, `%p` is defined to print pointer values in an "implementation-defined manner".