# Do memory addresses expressed in hexadecimal always need to start with '0x'?

Tags: c

Do memory addresses expressed in hexadecimal always need to start with '0x'? Or can it be any other? What are the conditions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    int *p = &n;
    
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

Here the output I got is '000000000062FE14'. Shouldn't it start with 0x?

Comment: The `0x` is a prefix that you use in source code to indicate to the compiler that what follows is a hexadecimal value.

Comment: From C standard: "*p - 
The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an **implementation-defined manner**.*"

Comment: But *technically* you have an undefined behavior here, as you are passing a pointer to `int` rather than `void`. So try converting it to `void*` and see if the behavior is changing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I guess the question is why the `%p` did not append `0x` to the value, and not what it seems from the title..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: in practice, a cast to `void *` would not alter the output.

Comment: Just OOC, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Note that if you use `scanf` with `%X` format spec, it accepts the input with or without `0x` prefix. However with `%i` you need to be specific.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The vast majority of implementations document the storage formats of `int*` and `void*` as being identical, and the authors of the Standard likely thought it obvious that passing representation-compatible things to a variadic function should "just work" on implementations intended for purposes other than portability validation, since there would be no reason for such implementations to process such things any other way.  Of course, if a compiler writer sees UB as unconditionally inviting gratuitously nonsensical behavior, all bets are off.

Comment: Not really a dup, but see [Why I am receiving a hexadecimal number as an output from my c program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75030901)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Seems like a dupe to me. Both of them boil down to "Why does `%p` not  (always) prefix the output with `0x` to make it clear it's hex?", and both of them lead to the same answers "1) It's implementation-defined, 2) Here's how to standardize it". I edited that one to improve the title (it omitted a "not" so it asked the question backwards, and wasn't clear on the involvement of pointers and %p); with the slight tweak, it's a fine dupe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am not receiving a hexadecimal number as output when I print a pointer address with %p?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75030901/why-i-am-receiving-a-hexadecimal-number-as-an-output-from-my-c-program)

Comment: @HarshilZahran "Do memory addresses expressed in hexadecimal always need to start with '0x'?"  This is a lot like asking, "Do words that are nouns always need to start with capital letters?"  In German they always do.  In English they do if they're proper nouns, or if they appear at the beginning of a sentence.  But of course there are exceptions, like the poet e.e. cummings.  So there's no one, hard-and-fast rule.  And it's the same way with hexadecimal numbers in programming, whether they're pointer values or otherwise.  They often begin with `0x`, but they don't have to.

Answer (score 6):

The format of `%p`'s outlook is implementation-defined. On [gcc](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw46LKzOvRCE3MTNPoyw/M0WTq5pLAQhAgnkKtgqmBtZwvlYBUEAtDyIAJgqKgOJpGkqqBTF5SjoKBZrWXLX//wMA) and [clang](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///XzkzLzmnNCVVwaa4JCUzXy/DjosrM69EITcxM0@jLD8zRZOrmksBCECCeQq2CqYG1nC@VgFQQC0PIgAmCoqA4mkaSqoFMXlKOgoFmtZctf//AwA) (at least the versions used by tio.run), it appears to get a `0x` prefix (and use lowercase for hex digits a-f), on your compiler it does not (and uses A-F instead). Both behaviors are legal.

If you want your code to behave in a consistent way, you'll need to use `%x` or `%X` as the base format code, so you can precisely specify the inclusion of `0x` exactly once. To preserve the width behavior you've already got (always a fixed number of zero-padded hex digits sufficient to represent any pointer value for that architecture), you'll need to explicitly specify the width as well. The final version (that ensures you get `0x000000000062FE14` on any 64 bit pointer architecture) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    int *p = &n;
    
    printf("0x%0*"PRIXPTR"\n", 2*(int)sizeof(p), (uintptr_t)p);
}
```

Breaking that down:

- `#include <inttypes.h>` provides (through `stdint.h`) the typedef for `uintptr_t`, and the macros for printing it portably
- `0x` is prefixed on manually (because the `#` modifier won't add `0x` for an input of zero, and we want it there even for `NULL` pointers)
- `0*` says "pad with zeroes out to a width of the first argument"
- `PRIXPTR` is a macro that produces the appropriate format code for uppercase hex relative to a `uintptr_t` (use `PRIxPTR` for lowercase hex)
- `2*(int)sizeof(p)` is passed to match the use of `*` for the width, which allows us to compute the size needed for exactly as many digits as the architecture requires to print any pointer of that type in the same fixed width. The cast to `int` is needed because `*` explicitly expects `int` for that argument, and `sizeof` produce `size_t`s; I'm fairly sure I can rely on `sizeof` for a pointer returning a value that fits in `int` though, so the cast is safe. :-)
- `(uintptr_t)p` casts to an integer type sufficient to hold any pointer to `void` (which means it can hold any pointer to object type, but outside of POSIX, there's no guarantee it can hold a function pointer); the `x`/`X` codes work with integers, not pointers, so it can't be passed as a pointer without violating the spec.

Technically, support for `[u]intptr_t` is optional (and requires at least C99/C++11, but hopefully that's not an issue). But I strongly suspect the systems that don't provide `[u]intptr_t` have pointers larger than *any* provided integer type (they'd be weirdo systems where `uintmax_t` may be smaller than the number of bits in a pointer, e.g. a system where programs are natively aware of memory across the cluster and can directly address it with 128 bit global address pointers that can refer to non-local memory, but the processor is still 64 bits, and the compiler doesn't bother to support combining two 64 bit registers to represent a single 128 bit integer, so `uintmax_t` is too small to fit a pointer address), so you'd have no way of handling them portably anyway (you'd be stuck with `%p`).

Comment: +1, but I note that technically, there doesn't need to be any particular relationship between the form output via `%p` and the one output via converting to an integer and using the appropriate conversion specifier for that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yar, `%p` could legally do just about anything that represents the information needed to describe the pointer uniquely (Want your implementation to print in base64? Still printable characters, go nuts!). My implementation was intended to match, as closely as possible, the observed behavior of the OP's particular implementation, but with a leading `0x`, and with portability to other systems (where `%p` might or might not pad, prefix with `0x`, use `a-f` vs. `A-F`, or not use hex at all), so humans and parsers looking for memory addresses in logs have a more consistent target.

Comment: "(uintptr_t)p casts to an integer type sufficient to hold any pointer;" better as '(uintptr_t)p casts to an integer type sufficient to hold any _object_ pointer;"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Sure, edited in (with slight elaboration). On POSIX, it can hold anything, but yeah, without POSIX guarantees or voluntary adherence to [J.5.7 (Function pointer casts)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.7), object pointers and function pointers have almost no points of intersection AFAICT (save that both are compatible with the null pointer).

Answer (score 4):

Since the format output by `%p` is "implementation-defined" by the C standard ([§7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)) and POSIX ([`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html)), different implementations do it differently.  Some include a `0x` prefix; some don't (and some might use `0X`, but I don't remember seeing that in use).  Many use lower-case letters for the digits 10-15; it seems your implementation uses upper-case, which is unusual.  Some implementations pad with leading zeros; many do not.  On macOS, a null pointer prints as `0x0` while other pointers print values like `0x7ffeebcf53bc`, so the width isn't necessarily fixed.

There is no requirement that there is uniformity across implementations.  If you want uniformity, use the type `uintptr_t` and macros such as `PRIXPTR` (or `PRIxPTR`) from `<inttypes.h>`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static_assert(sizeof(void *) == sizeof(void (*)(void)),
              "Object pointers are not the same size as function pointers");

#ifndef PTR_WIDTH
#define PTR_WIDTH "12"
#endif

#define PTR_FORMAT "0x%." PTR_WIDTH PRIXPTR

int main(void)
{
    printf("Object pointers:\n");
    int i = 0;
    int *a = malloc(3 * sizeof(*a));
    int *p = (int *)4100;

    printf("%p\n", (void *)0);
    printf("%p\n", &i);
    printf("%p\n", a);
    printf("%p\n", p);

    printf(PTR_FORMAT "\n", (uintptr_t)0);
    printf(PTR_FORMAT "\n", (uintptr_t)&i);
    printf(PTR_FORMAT "\n", (uintptr_t)a);
    printf(PTR_FORMAT "\n", (uintptr_t)p);

    printf("Function pointers:\n");
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(uintptr_t)main);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(uintptr_t)printf);
    printf(PTR_FORMAT "\n", (uintptr_t)main);
    printf(PTR_FORMAT "\n", (uintptr_t)printf);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

On a Mac, this produces:

```
Object pointers:
0x0
0x7ffee094539c
0x7ffed9405a10
0x1004
0x000000000000
0x7FFEE094539C
0x7FFED9405A10
0x000000001004
Function pointers:
0x10f2bddd0
0x7fff205f30a8
0x00010F2BDDD0
0x7FFF205F30A8
```

You will probably see different values, but the output should be similar.  On a Mac, I've never seen an address with more than 12 hexadecimal digits, so I set `PTR_WIDTH` to 12 (as a string).  You can set it to 16 (e.g. `gcc -o pp29 -DPTR_WIDTH='"16"' pp29.c`) if you want the maximum width for a 64-bit system, or use `8` if you're on a 32-bit system.

Note that you cannot officially convert function pointers to object pointers or vice versa directly in C:

[§6.2.5 Types ¶28](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28):

> A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.<sup>48)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.
>
> <sup>48)</sup> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.

[§6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶6-8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6):

> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.
>
> 7 A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned<sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.
>
> 8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sup>68)</sup>
> In general, the concept ''correctly aligned'' is transitive: if a pointer to type A is correctly aligned for a pointer to type B, which in turn is correctly aligned for a pointer to type C, then a pointer to type A is correctly aligned for a pointer to type C.

However §6.2.3.2 ¶6 provides an escape hatch — convert to an appropriate integer type — but be aware that in theory (though rarely in practice) there could be platforms where there isn't an integer type that can hold function pointers.  That is why there are two consecutive casts when printing the function addresses directly.

See also [§7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4):

> 1 The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>     intptr_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>     uintptr_t
> ```
>
> These types are optional.

It would be a very unusual machine where the `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` types are not available.

Comment: Huh. TIL that using `.<prec>` is, AFAICT, precisely equivalent to using `0<width>` for the integer format codes (both of them pad to the specified number of digits with zeroes, neither truncates). Been writing C for 20+ years and never noticed that. That's… odd. I don't like hard-coding the digit count to 12 based on a heuristic (I'd prefer a fixed-width equal to the maximum number of digits a pointer would need on the architecture), but then, I also don't like using `*` for runtime width, nor a chains preprocessing tests for compile-time computed width, so I'm stuck. :-)

Comment: The [C99 Rationale](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) documents in section 7.19.6.1 (p152) that "The use of leading zero in field widths to specify zero padding is superseded by a precision field. The older mechanism was retained."   I believe that comment was in the rationale for C90 (the C99 document covers both standards) — and sadly, there wasn't a rationale created for C11.

Comment: Huh. That's not much of a rationale; basically seems to boil down to "Hey, there's a new way (no justification for why, but likely an artifact of some other thing that needed to be nailed down), and we'll support both ways because why not?". So I guess back in the K&R days, using precision gave no such guarantees, and C90 specified it strictly enough that it did. Interesting.

Comment: The Unix 7th Edition (1978) manual page for [`printf()`](https://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/3/printf) says that the field width applies to floating point and string formats, but implies (by omission) that it does not apply to integer formats.  The C90 standard generalizes the notation, rendering the leading zero unnecessary, but retained it for backwards compatibility (so people could blithely continue to use it unaware of the alternative).

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, Concerning `(uintptr_t)main`:  The required `(u)intmax_t` may be wider than `(u)intptr_t`.  Since a function pointer could also be wider than `void *`, using `printf("0x%jX\n", (uintmax_t)main);` has a better chance at displaying more info than via `(uintptr_t)`.

Comment: With the code shown, if it compiles, then function pointers and object pointers must be the same size — the `static_assert()` ensures that.  If you're on a platform where that assertion fires, you might be able to use `uintmax_t` instead — you'd have to do investigation work on the platform.   There usually is a workaround available, but the details are platform-specific.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I strongly suspect that systems where `uintptr_t` does not exist are also systems where pointers are larger than `uintmax_t` (e.g. because they have some 128 bit global address space across a cluster, but still have register sizes of 64 bits and don't provide a `long long`-like type that logically combines two registers); I mentioned this near the end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75185857/364696). It's *possible* some lazy implementation which *could* provide `uintptr_t` would not, but I suspect the more likely case is "no integer type can fit a pointer".

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is not a question of existence, but of range. `UINTMAX_MAX >= UINTPTR_MAX` is certainly true.  There is scant downside to using `(uintmax_t)main` vs. `(uintptr_t)main`, yet a significant disadvantage may exist the other way around. IOWs, when a matching print specifier is not defined, using the `j` is a good first consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Tthe `%x` format has an option `%#x` which means that `"0x"` gets appended to the output. This isn't specified for `%p` however, but there are ways to safely convert the pointer to a large integer and then print:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 50;
    int *p = &n;
    printf("%"PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)p);
    printf("%#"PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)p);
}
```

Outputs something along the lines of:

```
7ffce1c44c04
0x7ffce1c44c04
```

Comment: Couple minor notes: 1) `#` won't add the `0x` when the value is zero, so when a `NULL` pointer is printed, you'd just see `0`, which is suboptimal, to my mind; putting the `0x` prefix in manually and omitting `#` gets consistency. 2) This ends up with non-fixed width output; not important for general hex output, but if you want to match how the OP's `%p` behaves (zero padding to make it fixed width for all pointers on the architecture), you'd need to explicitly specify zero padding and width. Perfectly fine if that's what the OP wants, but annoying to make it consistent with a specific `%p`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The internal representation of a null pointer isn't necessarily 0, and in case it is, why does it matter? As for formatting, the usual options of any integer are still available.

Comment: Yar, wasn't saying this was wrong in any way, just pointing out that it fixes one inconsistency between implementations while changing other things the OP may expect given the behavior of `%p` on their particular compiler. They seemed to expect `0x` to appear unconditionally, so I wanted to foreclose on the edge case (sure, null pointers aren't *required* to be `0`, but it's a rare system where they aren't), so when `p` is assigned `NULL`, they see `0x0` (or with padding, `0x00…00`), it doesn't switch from `0xdeadbeef` to plain `0` (might not be recognized as an address, by humans or parsers).

Answer (score 2):

> Do memory addresses of hexadecimals always need to end in '0x' form?

---

***Answer:*** No, they don't.

---

***From C11:***

> p
>
> The argument shall be a pointer to void. **The value of the pointer is
> converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
> implementation-defined manner.**

It's implementation-defined. And the pointer must be cast to `void *`, else your code invokes undefined behaviour.

```
printf ("%p\n", (void *) p);
```

Comment: tried with (void*) it still gives the same outout :/

Comment: My answer didn't state *casting to ```void *``` would prefix the output with ```0x```.* The output is printed in an *implementation-defined behaviour*. See @Lundin's answer below.

Comment: @Haris: Minor note for future: Using "above"/"below" gets out of date when voting changes answer ordering (or people select non-default orderings). Better to just say [See @Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186067/364696) using the `[See @Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186067/364696)` Markdown syntax (where that URL came from me clicking "Share" on the answer in question; yours would differ slightly) so position doesn't matter, and you direct link the answer instead of making the curious go on a hunt.

Answer (score 1):

%p is a format specifier for "pointers" and the interpretation, unlike some others, is "implementation dependent" so one cant really have an expectation of consistency, which is fair, given different environments can have different addressing semantics